# DEP3316 Error - Cannot deploy to Win10 Phone from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, win-universal-app

I am unable to deploy an application via Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to my Lumia 650. In the past it was possible but now I get the following error indicating to change the build configuration of a project or add an ARM device.

[image]

The build config is set to 'ARM', the device is connected via USB and my configuration manager looks like this.

[image]

[image]

The platform targets seem correct, so the config setting 'ARM' points to the platform target 'ARM'. I can run the app on my local computer, but I cannot deploy it to my phone. I also can't run the app in an emulator because if I choose the setting, VS does not change the caption and accept it.  I don't have any more ideas.

If it helps I could provide my .sln file with all build configurations if desired. The only thing I did was checking out my source code to a new location on my hard drive. Since then I couldn't deploy anymore. Someone got any hints?

UPDATE:

I cannot deploy to my phone, run the app in an emulator or run the app in the simulator. The only thing that works is running on the local machine. Even all new apps I create cannot be deployed or run in an emulator or simulator. Visual Studio and SDK repair installation was made, no notable change.

If I load an old Windows Phone 8.1 RT or Silverlight project everything works normally, I can use the emulator and I can deploy it to the phone.

Comment: Is the target device set to Device?

Comment: Sure, it worked before countless times in the way I did it today.

Comment: weird because it looks like it's trying to deploy the app to your pc.

Comment: So if it used to work on the previous location on your hard drive, you're clearly missing something vital to deployment. Do you still have the "old" solution located back there? If not, I would create a new project separately, and try to deploy that to the phone, if it works, you can start comparing the file structures in both projects to see what is missing or wrong.

Comment: I tried to create a new blank uwp app and I also could not deploy this one to my phone ... I guess a complete VS and SDK wipe is my next step -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your app in VS -> Properties -> Debugging

There is a combo box to select the target device. In my case there was no selection and I chose 'Device'. Now it works again.

https://dotblogs.com.tw/billchung/2016/04/03/051455